# How to compare great circle distance with euclidean distance of two sphere points using python?

Tags: python, numpy, euclidean-distance, great-circle

I am trying to check the error that is introduced when you compute the distance of two points on earth with the euclidean distance instead of using the great circle distance (gcd). I have two points that are defined by their lattitude and longtitude.
I used the python geopy framework for the [great circle distance](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/master/geopy/distance.py). Here the code for the gcd:

```
def measure(self, a, b):
        a, b = Point(a), Point(b)

        lat1, lng1 = radians(degrees=a.latitude), radians(degrees=a.longitude)
        lat2, lng2 = radians(degrees=b.latitude), radians(degrees=b.longitude)

        sin_lat1, cos_lat1 = sin(lat1), cos(lat1)
        sin_lat2, cos_lat2 = sin(lat2), cos(lat2)

        delta_lng = lng2 - lng1
        cos_delta_lng, sin_delta_lng = cos(delta_lng), sin(delta_lng)

        d = atan2(sqrt((cos_lat2 * sin_delta_lng) ** 2 +
                       (cos_lat1 * sin_lat2 -
                        sin_lat1 * cos_lat2 * cos_delta_lng) ** 2),
                  sin_lat1 * sin_lat2 + cos_lat1 * cos_lat2 * cos_delta_lng)

        return self.RADIUS * d
```

So or two points:

> p1=[39.8616,-75.0748], p2=[-7.30933,112.76]

the

> `gcd = 78.8433004543197 klm`

using the `great_circle(p1,p2).kilometers` function from geopy

I then transformed these two points in cartesian coordinates using this formula:

```
  def spherical_to_cartesian(r,la,lo):
       x=r*np.sin(90-la)*np.cos(lo)
       y=r*np.sin(90-la)*np.sin(lo)
       z=r*np.cos(90-la)
       return (x,y,z)
```

where `r=6372.795`, which results in the following cartesians coordinates

```
p1=[ -765.81579368,  -256.69640558,  6321.40405587], 
p2=[480.8302149,-168.64726394,-6352.39140142]
```

Then by typing: `np.linalg.norm(p2-p1)` i am getting `1103.4963114787836` as their euclidean norm which doesn't seem reasonable compared with ~78klm from the gcd. Am i inffering sth wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're comparing in the correct units?

Comment: not sure if this is your only error but np.sin and np.cos operate in radians...

Comment: The gdc seems very small. You have two points many degrees apart. I think 1 degree difference in position would be 100 km.

Comment: you are right!The problem was the way i am computing the cartesians. I should first convert to radians.Now i am getting 78.842797622886096 which is very close to gcd

Comment: From a [NJ turnpike tollbooth](https://www.google.com/maps/@39.861,-75.074,435m/data=!3m1!1e3) to somewhere in [Surabaya, Indonesia](https://www.google.com/maps/@-7.30933,112.76,435m/data=!3m1!1e3) if you were wondering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python includes two functions in the math package; radians converts degrees to radians, and degrees converts radians to degrees.

The method sin() returns the sine of x, in radians.

```
import math
def spherical_to_cartesian(r,la,lo):
   rlo = math.radians(lo)
   rla = math.radians(90-la)
   x=r*np.sin(rla)*np.cos(rlo)
   y=r*np.sin(rla)*np.sin(rlo)
   z=r*np.cos(rla)
   return (x,y,z)
```