# Measuring geographic distance with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, geographic-distance

I fail to use the outcome of `scipy`'s `pdist` function. I am interested in the real geographic distance (preferred unit: km). Take the following coordinates:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

coordinates = [ (42.057, -71.08), (39.132, -84.5155) ]
distance = pdist(coordinates)
print distance
# [ 13.75021037]
```

But what's the unit? Google says the distance between these two points is 1179 km. How do I get there from 13.75021037?

Comment: `pdist` , AFAICT, doesn't have any way to read the coordinates as lat-long. It's taking them as vectors in (AFAICT) R^n.  I believe you want to look for [spherical distance](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/Fpython_longitude_latitude) or [great circle distance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562739/how-to-compare-great-circle-distance-with-euclidean-distance-of-two-sphere-point?rq=1).

Comment: A better tool for what you want is geopy.  See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy for an example of using it to calculate geodesic distance between two points specified with lat and long.

Comment: @cphlewis: Thanks for the suggestion. One remark: Your first link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the latest Python 3, this now gives a deprecation warning. I actually found [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/84915) by [@cffk](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/3613/cffk) much easier to understand:

(pasting here for convenience)

```
>>> from geopy.distance import geodesic, great_circle
>>> p1 = (31.8300167,35.0662833) # (lat, lon) - https://goo.gl/maps/TQwDd
>>> p2 = (31.8300000,35.0708167) # (lat, lon) - https://goo.gl/maps/lHrrg
>>> geodesic(p1, p2).meters
429.1676644986777
>>> great_circle(p1, p2).meters
428.28877358686776
```

Answer (score 8):

The `pdist` method from `scipy` does not support distance for `lon`, `lat` coordinates, as mentioned at the comments.

However, if you like to get the kind of distance matrix that `pdist` returns, you may use the `pdist` method and the distance methods provided at the `geopy` package. To do so, `pdist` allows to calculate distances with a custom function with two arguments (a lambda function).

Here is an example:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from geopy.distance import vincenty
import numpy as np

coordinates = np.array([[19.41133431, -99.17822823],
                        [19.434514  , -99.180934],
                        [19.380412  , -99.178789])

# Using the vincenty distance function.

m_dist = pdist(coordinates, # Coordinates matrix or tuples list
               # Vicenty distance in lambda function
               lambda u, v: vincenty(u, v).kilometers)
```