# How to create distance table using geodesic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopy

I'm calculating with Python. Let's say i have this kind of DataFrame where it consists of long lat of some points

```
import pandas as pd
dfa=pd.DataFrame(([1,2],[1,3],[1,1],[1,4]), columns=['y','x'])
```

before, i used distance matrix from scipy.spatial and create another DataFrame with this code. but it seems that it can't precisely calculate the distance between points (with long lat)

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(dfa.values, dfa.values), index=dfa.index, columns=dfa.index)
```

Do you think it's possible to change the calculation with geodesic? here what i've tried.

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic
pd.DataFrame(geodesic(dfa.values[0], dfa.values[0]).kilometers, index=dfa.index, columns=dfa.index)

# i don't know how to change [0] adjusted to column and index
```

any suggestion?

Comment: `geopy` is the way to do this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632190/measuring-geographic-distance-with-scipy

Comment: thank you, i've tried that before but i want the output to be DataFrame of distance matrix. is it possible though?

Comment: `geodesic` only does two points at a time.  You'll have to do two nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a list or list-like object `locations`, you can do

```
distances = pd.DataFrame([[geodesic(a,b) for a in locations] 
                          for b in locations])
```

This will be redundant, though, since it will calculate distance for both a,b and b,a, even though they should be the same. Depending on the cost of `geodesic`, you may find the some of the following alternatives faster:

```
distances = pd.DataFrame([[geodesic(a,b)  if a > b else 0 
                           for a in locations] 
                              for b in locations])
distances = distances.add(distances.T)
```

```
size = len(locations)
distances = pd.DataFrame(columns = range(size), index = range(size))
def get_distance(i,j):
    if distances.loc[j,i]:
        return distances.loc[j,i]
    if i == j:
        return 0
    return geodesic(locations[i], locations[j])
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        distances.loc[i,j] = get_distance(i,j)
```

You can also store the data as a dictionary with the keys being output from `itertools.combinations`. There's also [this article](https://blog.sopticek.net/2016/07/24/implementing-symmetric-matrix-in-python/) on creating a symmetric matrix class.